# when is rational function regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, functions

In general, how does one determine if a rational function is regular? I have the particular problem of determining in which points of the circle $V(x^2+y^2-1) \subseteq A^2$is the rational function $\alpha= \frac{y-1}{x}$ regular?

Comment: For your example: no, because $(0, -1)$ is in the curve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To say that $\phi= \frac{y-1}{x}$ is regular on the circle means that there exist   polynomials $p(X,Y), q(X,Y)\in k[X,Y]$ such that: $$Y-1=X\cdot p(X,Y)+q(X,Y)\cdot(X^2+Y^2-1)\in  k[X,Y]$$ But substituting $X=0$  in that equality yields $$Y-1=q(0,Y)\cdot(Y^2-1) \in k[Y] $$ which is impossible since the left hand side has degree $1$ whereas the right hand side is 
zero or has degree $\geq2$.
Hence the rational function $\phi$ is not regular.

**Edit**
 Since $\phi$ is not regular but is clearly regular at all points of the circle different from $P=(0,-1)$, it follows that $P$ is the only point where $\phi$ is not regular, i.e. the only pole of $\phi$.

Comment: ...and this also shows that algebraic geometry is often far less frightful than supposed :-)

Comment: This is incorrect, since $\frac{1-y}{x}=\frac{x}{1+y}$ which is defined for almost all but $(0,-1)$.

Comment: @José Alejandro Aburto Araneda.  What I wrote is perfectly correct, despite your irrelevant comment: a regular function must be defined **at all points**, and that a rational function is defined **"for almost all"** points (as you write) certainly does not make it regular. Actually **all** rational functions are defined at almost all points, but most of these rational functions are not regular!

Comment: The question is determine in which points is regular, not only if it is regular or not. In your proof you are missing $(0,1)$.

Comment: @José Alejandro Aburto Araneda: I am missing nothing in my proof, which shows that $\phi$ is not regular, and does not state explicitly where $\phi$ is regular. I had not addressed this question in my proof, since I thought it was perfectly clear once we know that $\phi$ is not rational. I have written an edit making this explicit.