# General way of determine where a rational function $\phi\in k(X)$ is not regular

Tags: algebraic-geometry, rational-functions, divisors-algebraic-geometry

So, if you have an irreducible variety $X$ over $k=\bar{k}$ and you consider a rational function $\phi=f/g\in k(X)$, is there a general way to determine where $\phi$ is not regular?

At this point I would like to avoid sheaf-theoretic stuff, as long as it is possible.

**What I know**

*If you only have one point where $f$ could not be regular* then you only have to prove that $f\notin k[X]$. This is what happens with $X=V(x^2+y^2−1)$ and $(y-1)/x$ here: [when is rational function regular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727622/when-is-rational-function-regular)
However, in that particular case it is simple and you have a trick adapted.

*If you suspect that $f$ could not be regular at the hypersurface $Y\subset X$ at some regular points of $X$* then you can use the local equation $\pi$ of $Y$ in certain open set to compute the number $M_g$ such that $g\in(\pi^{M_g})$ ($M_g$ max., $M_f$ similar). So $\phi$ is regular iff $M_f-M_g\geq0$. These $M$ are usually denoted $v_Y(g)$.

**What I don't know**

What happens in general? In particular: What happens with the singular points of $X$? And if $Y$ has greater codimension?

Comment: I think you should cover $X$ by some affine varieties $X_j$ and exploit that $k[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$ is a UFD so every regular function on $X_j$ is represented by a polynomial $\in k[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$

Comment: @reuns I think that the problem with that is that there are different representations for a rational function. To "simplify" "zeros" and "poles" you can do what I said about divisors, but in general that doesn't work (as far as I know).